# No filters in facetedData after Upgrade 2.2

Tags: upgrade, filter, product-collection

I have made a small extension with **2.1.*** for

```
multiselect-filtering.
```

A part of the code is:

```
$productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
...
$originalFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
```

This returned the facetedData depending on the applied  filters. After the Upgrade to `2.2` it only returns the counts of all products per option and ignores the applied filters completely.

I doubled checked in debugging that the filters in the `productCollection` are really set.

How can I gain the former result? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!